# How I hide the chat window in Google Drive Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-drive, chat, google-spreadsheets

I sometimes accidentally open the chat window when using Google Drive's Spreadsheet app. I couldn't figure out how to close it. Any ideas?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Isn't there any hide chat icon?

Well in my computer it's showing a hide chat option.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I can't find the Hide Chat button. I also couldn't figure out how to launch the chat window in the first place (I always accidentally trigger it).